# How to go to another page after login in Spring security

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

Here is the jsp file that shows details of the flight information.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ include file="../layout/taglib.jsp" %>

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped ">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Flight No</th>
            <th>Flight destination</th>
            <th>Flight origin</th>
            <th>Book now</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <form:form commandName="reserv" action="flight-reservation" cssClass="form-horizontal">
            <c:forEach items="${flightInfos}" var="flightInfo">
                <tr>
                    <td>${flightInfo.flightNo}</td>
                    <td>${flightInfo.destination}</td>
                    <td>${flightInfo.origin}</td>
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Book now" class="btn btn-primary"></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </form:form>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the Spring security configuration file.

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/users**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/flight-reservation**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

    <form-login login-page="/login.html"/>
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
    <logout logout-url="/logout" />
</http>
```

This is the controller for the flight-reservation

```
@RequestMapping("/flight-reservation")
public String showReservation(){
    return "flight-reservation";
}
```

Here I want to user to log in to the system if he clicks on "Book now" button. Then after he logged in, he should be redirected to another page which consist of another form to get other user details. When I run this code, login works with Spring security. I'm new to these Spring and Spring security. I'm very glad if anyone can help me to solve this problem or giving advice to find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my question. Just changed the url pattern of the form in above jsp page. I changed it as `action='/flight-demo/flight-reservation.html'`. In here `flight-reservation.html` is the page that needed to be redirected after I logged in to the system. I have already created this jsp file. No need to change My controller and `security.xml` files.

Answer (score 2):

Add `default-target-url="/page_to_be_redirected_after_login.html"` into the `<form-login`

Comment: I tried this, but it is not working for me. Do I need to change the controller or may I know, what can I do to solve it? Please help me @StanislavL